# how to create a formula to return values with 3 digit

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Please help me to create a formula for the following decimal place condition

```
111.000     =   111
11.100      =   11.1
1.110       =   1.11
0.111       =   0.111
0.011       =   0.011
```

I tried "round" formula, but the result return trailing zeros

I need to return the value with 3 digit

Comment: How your input data is stored? As number or as text? If it's number, then setting "number formatting" as "general" should solve your problem.

Comment: yes,input as number, when i use the round formula,it works but leaves trailing zeros

Comment: you need to change number format too.

Answer (score 0):

*To achieve data in desire format you need to apply following Formulas.*

**Formula for Result 1:**

```
=IF(ROUND(A1,3)=INT(A1),TEXT(A1,"0"),TEXT(A1,"0.0##"))
```

**Formula for Result 2, total 3 digits:**

```
=IF(ROUND(A1,3)=INT(A1),TEXT(A1,"0"),TEXT(A1,"##.0##"))
```

[image]

**N.B.**

- Apply `TEXT cell Format` to **Original 
  data** since neither `NUMBER` nor 
  `GENERAL` Format supports the form of 
  data shown by you.
- In Formula 1,

  **TEXT(A1,`"0.0##"`))**, `0.0##` 
  is editable, which sets digits as decimal 
  place maximum `3`, if less then apply leading 
  Zero.
- In Formula 2,

  **TEXT(A1,`"##.0##"`))**, `##.0##` is editable, 
  which Formats data without leading Zero before 
  decimal.